# WEB SQL: How to search if ID is existing on one table then insert data on another table?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, web-sql

I know WEB SQL is deprecated, but I am using it now as my initial database.
My web app is a time record app in which user will enter his/her ID number then click submit. The app will search on one table (emp_info) if the ID exist. If it exist, the ID , date and time will be added on another table (emp_log).

I was able to search on the first table (emp_info). My problem is that I cannot add on the other table (emp_log).

Here's my part of the search in my HTML:

```
<form>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <input type="number" id="emp_id" placeholder="Enter ID Number" autofocus>
    <button  type="button" id="btn_submit" onclick="addLogs();">SUBMIT</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here's my JAVASCRIPT:

```
if (window.openDatabase) {

  var empdb = openDatabase("etrs_db3", "0.1", "Employee Time Record System", 1024 * 1024);

  empdb.transaction(function (t) {
    t.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS emp_info (emp_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, emp_fname TEXT, emp_lname TEXT)");
  });

  empdb.transaction(function (t) {
    t.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS emp_log (emp_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC, emp_date TEXT, emp_time TEXT)");
  });

} else {
  alert("WebSQL is not supported by your browser!");
}

function addLogs() {

  if (empdb) {
    var empid = document.getElementById("emp_id").value;
    // JUST MADE THIS AS SAMPLE DATE AND TIME
    var empdate = "04-01-2016";
    var emptime = "09:00 am";
    // SEE IF TEXTBOX HAS INPUT
    if (empid !== "") {
      //SEARCH
      empdb.transaction(function (t) {
        t.executeSql("SELECT * FROM emp_info WHERE emp_id=?", [empid], function (t, results) {
           var row = results.rows.length;
           if (row !== 0) {
             // ADD
             empdb.transaction(function (t) {
               t.executeSql("INSERT INTO emp_log (emp_id, emp_date, emp_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [empid, empdate, emptime]);
             });
           } else {
             alert("ID number not found!");
           }
        }, null);
      });
    } else {
      alert("Pls enter your ID number.");
    }
  } else {
    alert("db not found, your browser does not support web sql!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you getting a syntax error for `var emptime = 09:00 am`? A string needs to be in quotes.

Comment: And `var empdate = 04-01-2016` is equivalent to `var empdate = -2013` because you're subtracting numbers, not creating a date.

Comment: oh yeah sorry... I also tried fixing that but still wasn't able to add.
gonna edit the code bytheway, thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: Change your button to `type="button"`. Otherwise it will submit the form and reload the page.

Comment: ok, will do that too! thank u!